# Understanding Python List Memory Usage In Recursive Calls

Tags: python, c, memory-management, recursion

I just wanted to check if I understood Python's memory management correctly.

The following function would use *O(j)* memory, but **not** *O(nj)* memory, since the parameter *n* is a reference to the list, but not the list itself.

```
def cool(n,j):
    if j == 0:
        return
    return cool(n,j-1)
```

Also, say this function was written in C, am I correct in assuming that, with C, its memory usage would be *O(nj)*, since a copy of the list/array would be created for each recursive call.

Comment: This function uses constant memory (ignoring the overhead of the call stack, otherwise O(j) memory is correct); it just takes O(j) calls to return None.

Comment: @chepner: Not counting the memory used by the call stack...

Comment: In C, it depends on what type `n` actually *is*; the array is probably passed as the address of the array, not the entire array itself.

Comment: I assume that `n` is a list, or a C array. Neither Python nor C create a copy of the list / array, only a reference is passed in the recursive call.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Each recursive step will use O(1) memory: function call overhead, and one pointer for each function parameter.

You can experimentally verify this by creating a large object (`x = "x" * 1024 * 1024 * 100`), then recursing on it a number of times and checking the process's memory usage:

```
def recurse(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        raw_input("done! Check memory usage now.")
        return
    return recurse(x, n - 1)

recurse(x, 1000)
```